# Infinite loop happenning

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the following function :

```
void  dump() const
{
    size_t      it = 0;

    std::cout << "[";
    while (it < this->_size);
    {
        std::cout << (this->_arr)[it];
        if ((this->_arr)[it + 1])
            std::cout << ", ";          
        it++;
    }
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
}
```

This appears to cause an infinite loop, I'm guessing it comes from a bad use of `std::cout`, and `std::endl`, but I can see how to manage this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd believe you, if there was no `while` loop.

Comment: Also, I hope your `this->_arr` contains `this->_size + 1` items, or you will access the "array" out of bounds.

Comment: Remove *;* after while.

Comment: You missed brackets after while keyword.

Comment: If the `;` behind while is in your actual code, then that's your infinite loop

Comment: @herohuyongtao Why you spoil all the elaborate standard-quoting undefined behavior invoking explanations???

Comment: "Infinite loop caused by std::cout" - ***NOPE.***

Comment: (I'm wondering, how can one **possibly** say "hey, I've written some code and it's not working, I'm SURE it will be a problem with the standard library. No, it's certainly not me who have made a typo, no way!")

Comment: BTW, modern compilers (GCC, clang, ...) and code quality tools (cppcheck, ...) warn you about this. **Turn on the darn compiler warnings.**

Comment: The most trivial attempt at debugging would have revealed this problem.

Comment: @H2CO3 I totally agree. However, for compilers like VS, there will be no warning about this even turning it on.

Comment: I compile with -W -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic, and I got no warnings for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I have commented, you need to change

```
while (it < this->_size);
```

to

```
while (it < this->_size)
```

to make it a `while`-loop with the ability to change its condition in order to avoid infinite loop.